# Interpreting a profiling file (Rprof)

Tags: r, profiling

I have code which takes a lot of time executing:

```
dataRaw<-pblapply(femme,function (x) {

  article<-user(x,date=FALSE,weight=FALSE)
  names<-rep(x,length(article))  
  result<-matrix(c(names,article),ncol=2)

})
dataRaw<-do.call(rbind,dataRaw)
dataRaw[,3]<-vector(length=length(dataRaw[,2]))
dataRaw[,3]<-pbapply(dataRaw,1,function(x){
  Rprof(filename = "profile.out")
  revisions<-revisionsPage(x[2])
  rank<-rankingContrib(revisions,50)
  rank<-rank$contrib
  x[1] %in% rank
  Rprof(NULL)
})
result<-as.vector(dataRaw[dataRaw$ranking==TRUE,2])
```

Lanching the summaryRprof function, it give me this

```
$by.self
                        self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
".Call"                      0.46    95.83       0.46     95.83
"as.data.frame.numeric"      0.02     4.17       0.02      4.17

$by.total
                             total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"FUN"                              0.48    100.00      0.00     0.00
"pbapply"                          0.48    100.00      0.00     0.00
".Call"                            0.46     95.83      0.46    95.83
"<Anonymous>"                      0.46     95.83      0.00     0.00
"GET"                              0.46     95.83      0.00     0.00
"request_fetch"                    0.46     95.83      0.00     0.00
"request_fetch.write_memory"       0.46     95.83      0.00     0.00
"request_perform"                  0.46     95.83      0.00     0.00
"revisionsPage"                    0.46     95.83      0.00     0.00
"as.data.frame.numeric"            0.02      4.17      0.02     4.17
"as.data.frame"                    0.02      4.17      0.00     0.00
"data.frame"                       0.02      4.17      0.00     0.00
"rankingContrib"                   0.02      4.17      0.00     0.00

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 0.48
```

Appears it is the ".Call" function which takes all the machine time. What is this .Call entry?

Comment: You need to tell us what packages you're using. But it looks like the functions that call the `.Call` interface to compiled code are making some sort of network request. You're unlikely to be able to make that faster.

Comment: i'm building a package called WikiSocio to make some data mining on MediaWiki pages. the functions revisionsPage, rankingContrib came from this. And otherwise i use httr

Comment: Try `proftools` package to parse the Rprof log file. See vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proftools/proftools.pdf

Comment: It's saying that the line with `revisionsPage` is taking almost all the time. When I'm profiling in R, I prefer to look directly at the profiler output file. It contains a bunch of stack samples. Pick one at random. In your case the chances are 19/20 that it will show you exactly what the problem is, who's calling what, and why. If you're not sure, look at one or two more.